# HBase table is empty, but regions are increased

Tags: hbase, ttl, regions

I created a table below, I have wrote some data to this table.

```
**Namespace   Table Name       Online Regions          Description**
default user_recommend_stories  17  'user_recommend_stories', {NAME => 'a', TTL => '259200 SECONDS (3 DAYS)'}, {NAME => 'c', TTL => '259200 SECONDS (3 DAYS)'}
```

The table was empty when I scan it after 3 days. But the number of online regions is still 17. How to release the space of these regions?

Answer (score 1):

HBase doesn't support region deletes (or merges), neither manually nor as a result of compaction.

Comment: Does this mean that the number of regions will increase, but will not increase the number of disk space?

Comment: As the table grows, so is the number and size of each region. Once the region reaches a certain limit, it is split according to split policy. Going forward you will see the number of regions increase.